# Django solr-thumbnail redis configuration

Tags: django, redis, sorl-thumbnail

**Why is the [`thumbnail`](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/template.html?highlight=empty#template-tags-and-filters) template tag not working for the setup as detailed below?**

The Django project is configured in this way (extracts of relevant files):

**settings.py** (extract)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ..
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    ..
)

..

# solr-thumbnail related settings
THUMBNAIL_FORMAT = 'PNG'
THUMBNAIL_KVSTORE = 'sorl.thumbnail.kvstores.redis_kvstore.KVStore'
THUMBNAIL_REDIS_HOST = 'localhost' # default
THUMBNAIL_REDIS_PORT = '6379' # default
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    profile_pic = ImageField(upload_to='user_profile_imgs')
```

**views.py** (extract)

```
form = NewUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    user_inst = UserProfile(
        email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
        profile_pic=request.FILES['image']
    )
    user_inst.save()
    return ..
```

**HTML template** (extract)

```
<p>Actual image</p> <!-- THIS WORKS -->
<img src="{{ user.profile_pic.url }}" alt="user profile pic"> 

<p>Cropped image</p> <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK -->
{% thumbnail user.profile_pic "100x100" crop="smart" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="user profile pic 100 by 100">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

The cropped image does not work; according to the [sorl-django workflow](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1wlE4LkQpzXd2a2Nxfjt6_j5NG7889dzMyf0V-xPAJSE/edit?hl=en) the newly requested image should be created if the key is not found the Redis-cache which I have configured. And indeed when checked the redis cache has no items at all:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
(empty list or set)
```

So sorl-thumbnail is not even creating the keys on redis. I can't figure what the problem is as I get no exception whatsoever. I have the feeling I'm missing a step somewhere.

Relevant Python package versions (via yolk):

```
Django          - 1.5.1        - active
Pillow          - 2.0.0        - active
redis           - 2.7.6        - active
sorl-thumbnail  - 11.12        - active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the template does not work one should add:

```
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
```

to the settings file and then *useful* exceptions as to why the `thumbnail` template tag is not working will be produced. (It is highly recommended to *disable* this setting in production.)

I then had to do 2 fixes to get the above working:

First: changed

```
THUMBNAIL_REDIS_PORT = '6379'
```

to an integer:

```
THUMBNAIL_REDIS_PORT = 6379
```

Second: changed the image parameter to the `thumbnail` tag to be the image's URL rather than simply the image AND the crop mode to "center" instead of "smart", i.e. I changed:

```
{% thumbnail user.profile_pic "100x100" crop="smart" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="user profile pic 100 by 100">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

to:

```
{% thumbnail user.profile_pic.url "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="user profile pic 100 by 100">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

That did it! I still would like to use [smart cropping](http://smileychris.com/ramblings/sorl-thumbnail-now-smarter-cropping/) though; if you have any ideas with regards to this please add an answer/comment. Thanks.